# MFC WYSIWYG editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, wysiwyg, document-view

I want to make an application in Visual C++ 2012 using MFC frameworks using Document/View structure; I want edit my view (that is the main window) with an editor, not handcoding, but Visual Studio seems that can edit in WYSIWYG mode just dialog boxes; I don't want to make a 'dialog based application', I want to make a Document/View application and edit my View with an editor WYSIWYG; Any solution?

Comment: This isn't going to help you with your immediate problem, but you should read it nonetheless: [Does Visual Studio Rot the Mind?](http://www.charlespetzold.com/etc/doesvisualstudiorotthemind.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use CFormView as a base class when you creating your MFC application. [image: CFormView]

If you already have a project, then add a new form using the class wizard. Select CFormView as a base class.

When you open Resource View your new form will be listed in "Dialog" folder[image: CFormView editor]

Answer (score 3):

In the last step of the wizard that creates a new document/view application, change the view base class from CView to CFormView. When you do that the CFormView can be edited just like a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

MFC based apps have a WYSIWYG editor.  Open the Resource Files folder of your dialog, SDI or MDI project and then open the .rc file.  Menus and a toolbox should open up ready for editing.

Comment: I don't have dialog; Using Document/View, code generator doesn't make me dialog box! i have a CView, and I want to edit it

Comment: No. You selected a CView a sa view, but with a CFormView you have exactly what all other are writing: A WYSIWIG Editor for dialogs.